# I can't answer a Stack Exchange question

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, comments

I tried to answer a question where Gmail thinks someone is trying to access your account. The question mentions the person has VPN. But Stack Exchange prevents me giving an answer as I don't have 50 points yet. How does Stack Exchange get any answers from newbies ever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you tried to post your answer as a comment as the privilege that requires 50 reputation points is [comment everywhere](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). [new user restrictions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user), including answering protected questions, are lift when a user reach 10 reputation points.

Please read the first link to learn about how comments should be used on this site.

Related

- [How do I write write a good answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)
- [What is a “protected” or "highly active" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764/289691)
- [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/289691)

Comment: Hmmm  I cant even upvote the answer to say it helped me.  Maybe StackOverflow is not for me.

Comment: @FrankKolmann: You don't necessarily have to upvote to say it helped.  You *accept* the answer by clcking the tick mark.

Comment: @FrankKolmann Another possible explanation could be that it is a [protected question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/protected-questions/info). (This one seems like the one described in your post: [Gmail "suspicious sign-in prevented" message - is it legit?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26600). And it [is protected](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/26600/revisions).)

Comment: Yeah thats the one.  I use Proton VPN and google gmail occasionally has fits when the VPN assigns IP addresses very different to my ususal IP.  It is not phishing or a scam it is google not playing well with VPNs.  Google says it is for our protection, but when I travel it makes gmail very very hard for me. The recovery process uses a recovery phone number and if I cant access my phone to get the google sms code I cannot recover or use my gmail.  FWIW I thought maybe you guys had a better solution.

Comment: ps.  Nice site, I understand now why the ratings system is as it is and I agree that it is necessary.  It is probably there already but a link to a guide to how to use the site would be useful to me.  You guys have already given me links, I am thinking more like a tutorial on how to use Stack Exchange itself.

Comment: We have [tour] and [help] and many pages have tips and links to the corresponding help articles but we don't have a step-by-step tutorial.